# Technique to make a simple product configurator with basic JS,HTML,CSS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Any small hints / tips for the best techniques or way to structure my javascript code? How to combine the arrays, values, functions in the right way. I need to make a tool for a smoothie shop owner where clients can choose ingredients of choice but we need to calculate the total amount of sugar and vitamins eg. And i can't grasp how to combine all these parameters into Javascript.

> EarlyBirdSmootie: Apple: Vitamin A = UI200  Vitamin C = UI300 Sugar =
>   200mg
>
> Pear: Orange C = UI 3000 Vitamin A = UI1000 Sugar = 250mg
>
> Orange: Vitamin C = UI3000 Sugar = 250mg
>
> Each fruit has a special mix of Vitamin and Sugar eg. Orange= C
>   Vitamin 3000UI + 250mg sugar

**Product builder with an overview**
So when a staff orders a smoothie with Apple, Pear & Orange we need to know the total amount of VitaminsUI and SugarMG + a view of the individual Vitamin and Sugar of each ingredient.

**Editing option for a created product**
Preferable we need to be able the create a list of bestselling soups we can reuse + add or remove and ingredient to the soup.

**What is the best technique to use for this and how should i do this?**

I have hear made a rough estimation of how i would do this so i can get going:

Here is my mockup so far:
http://madsschou.com//YuppieSmootieTest/index.html

As you see i have to be able to add ingredients, amount, put it in a cart, while all sugar and vitamin levels are still shown.

```js
// Custom function
function calculateTip() {

// Store the data of inputs
var vitaminTypes = document.getElementById("vitaminTypes").value;
var vitaminAmount = document.getElementById("vitaminAmount").value;
var sugarAmount = document.getElementById("sugarAmount").value;
var ingredientTypes = document.getElementById("ingredientTypes").value;
    
// Quick validation
if(fruitAmount === "" || serviceQuality == 0) {
window.alert("Please enter some values to get this up and running!");
return; // this will prevent the function from continuing
}
    
// Check to see if this input is empty or less than or equal to 1
if(numFruits === "" || numFruits <= 1) {
numPeople = 1;
        
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";        
} else {
        
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "block";        
}
    
// Do some math!
var total = (vitaminType * vitaminAmount) ;
total = Math.round(total * 100);
total = total.toFixed(2);
    
    
// Display the content!
document.getElementById("totalAmount").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = total;
}

// Hide the content info amount on load
document.getElementById("totalAmount").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("each").style.display = "none";

// Clicking the button calls our custom function
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() { calculateAmount(); }
```

Comment: Good approach would to make your code snippet executable. Afterwards, can you be more specific what your problem is and which approach have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is more complicated task to do in JS than i thought. I was mainly looking for a similar project source code the get inspiration from or some tips that can get me going in the right direction, since i feel there is still a long way before this code will be working. As you see in the website link i need to calculate the sum of vitamin content of each smoothies a person makes. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly saying I did not fully understand your code, but here are some of my suggestions:

- replace `==` with `===`, like in this one: `serviceQuality == 0`, because javascript will coerce when doing `==` comparison: `'' == 0 // true`
- It seems that the variable `numPeople` is not initialized in your function. This makes the function not pure, which may cause bugs later when your code base grows. Try use it as an argument
- It appears that you deal with a lot of styling in your js code, which can also (maybe better) accomplished by CSS and pseudo class like `:valid`. Using CSS will not only makes your code simpler, but also more robust. You doing such style manipulation will cause a lot of repaint. If you are going to switch to CSS, I also recommend [reading](https://csstriggers.com/) this!
- I am not sure about this point, but I think it's better to use `addEventListener('click', ... )` than directly attach `onclick` method
- Or you can try some framework like React, Angular2, Ember, which may make the task easier to accomplish

Hope these may help! \[.__.]/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is more complicated task to do in JS than i thought. I was mainly looking for a similar project source code the get inspiration from or some tips that can get me going in the right direction, since i feel there is still a long way before this code will be working. Is Angular going to make this much easier? (considering i need to learn a new framework)
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: As you can always google "best framework for task x", here are some of my suggestion: If you are coming from Java/C++ and like strong typing, I suggest using Angular 2 since it uses TypeScript. If you want the framework coming out with almost everything you need, try Ember. I personally use React extensively as it makes more sense to me than other framework/library. (technically React is just a library:) )